# AngularJS - store page data

Tags: json, angularjs, storage

I would like to store my datas with local storage or cookie. The data source is a json and this json has a data limitation (10 data per page). So I implemented a "show more" function, which is loads the other jsons when I click a button.

My problem is that I can't store properly the whole loaded datas. I tried with different techniques, but nothing.

Here is the html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="getItems()" ng-hide="items.length == 0">show more</button>
</div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    var page = 1;

    $scope.getItems = function () {
        var url = 'https://differentdomain.com/json&page=' + page++;

        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (status == 200) {
                    $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(data.results);
                    // or other way
                    // $scope.items.push.apply($scope.items, data.results)
                } else {
                    console.error('Error happened while getting list.')
                }
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.error('Error happened while getting the list.')
            });
    };

    $scope.getItems();
});
```

Anybody has idea, how can I store it the loaded datas?

Comment: What is the problem? And where is the code to store to local storage or to cookie?

Comment: Please can you be more precise? What you get in `$scope.items` after running `$scope.getItems()` the first time? And what after the second?

Comment: you dont need check the `status code` inside `success` function because the call was `successful`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to know is hot to store data you can just use localStorage.setItem to save data and localStorage.getItem to retrieve those data.

The simplest implementation would be

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    //retrieving saved object or init new array

    $scope.getItems = function () {
        //XXX if page is last one then return;
        //current page is basically num of objects divided by page size (10 in this case)
        var page = ($scope.items.length / 10) + 1;
        var url = 'https://differentdomain.com/json&page=' + page++;

        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (status == 200) {
                    $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(data.results);
                    //saving current object
                    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify($scope.items));
                } else {
                    console.error('Error happened while getting list.')
                }
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.error('Error happened while getting the list.')
            });
    };
    $scope.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
    if (!$scope.items.length) $scope.getItems();

});
```

Comment: I got this error message: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Comment: The first load is working, after I got this message. What did I forget?

Comment: Use `try catch` around the JSON.parse to debug the value of the localStorage string when it fails, you're putting some `undefined` inside the localStorage and that's why you get the error. Without some more info i cannot help you just by guessing.

Comment: I didn't get any undefined, just the stored objects:
`{items: "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[o…],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]", length: 1}`

Comment: Was it helpful for you?

Comment: My bad, object needed to be converted in json, i added `JSON.stringify` in the code. Try now.

Comment: I'm really appreciate your help. I didn't change the code with the "stringify", because there is a new situation. After I removed the wrong stored objects, I got a different error message:
`[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys`. I managed that problem with this:
`ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`. So without code changing started to work, but not perfect. I got the first 10 item. The more button also good, just when I refresh the page, the next 10 item goes to the end of the list (without push the "more" button).

Comment: The calculation of the new page should've been inside the `getItems` function, i edited the snippet. But also there can be other problems: 1. You need to clear the localStorage when you want to test the feature so, before refreshing the page. 2. As i commented you need to handle the MAX pages otherwise you'll end up asking for non existent pages.

Comment: It didn't work. I remove the storage, but when I refresh the page, increases the number.

Comment: I figured out something, which is working, but maybe not the best solution. The end of the code:   `if(localstorage.getItems("items") === null) { $scope.getItems(); }` In this way I can avoid to load always, instead of just once.

Comment: In this case you can do everything with just one command at the end, i updated the example. In this way you wont read twice from the localStorage that is a very heavy operation.

Comment: Your latest code update doesn't work for me if I load the data at the first time. If the storage already exists, perfect, without I get error. Weird.

Comment: Uhm, thats probably because getItems wasn returning anything. I Updated with a simpler code

Comment: That is perfect now. Thank you for your help indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The above should work, I assume it is loading 10 more each time you click the button.

Your question seems to be how can you persist those loaded items between browser sessions. If so my suggestion would be for you to look at:

https://github.com/goodeggs/angular-cached-resource

This abstracts away all the difficult parts such as persistence and cache retrieval to give you a consistent API.